# What's the difference between ps processname* | kill and kill -p processname* in powershell?

Tags: powershell, kill

In powershell, is there a difference between:

```
ps theProcessName* | kill
```

and

```
kill -processname theProcessName*
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively, the answer is "no."

`ps [processname] | kill` will query for a list of objects matching 'processname' and pass those objects to the `kill` command.

`kill -processname [processname]` will kill all processes matching 'processname'.

The only difference is how the commands work on the backend. For `ps [processname] | kill`, Powershell will first perform a `Get-Process` command, then pass it to kill. `kill -processname [processname]` will simply issue a `Stop-Process` command, without querying for their existence first.

Short answer: they will both perform the same task. the straight `kill` command is very slightly faster, because one step is skipped.

Answer (score 1):

Well, "ps processname" doesn't do anything.  And "kill -p" doesn't kill.  It prints.

Comment: powershell, not bash;

Comment: right, I edited my question that it's in powershell